# Having issues with getting page name to update

Tags: php

Ok, so I have been coding a marketplace script for my website in I been trying to get theses links to work, For some reason when a user clicks on the links the page name doesn't update to the new page that they're viewing the rest of the page update but not the page name. So my links show like this dashboard.php?account=withdraws. on the website the dashboard pagename still shows in never updates. So I have included my PHP code of the dashboard I hope somebody can help me resolve this.

Here's the top of the dashboard

```
<?php
// Seddeo Page System - Customer Dashboard
DEFINE("IN_SEDDEO", 1);

$pageName = "Dashboard";
$body = "customer-dashboard";

require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once('inc/header.php');

$account = $_GET['account'];
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

// If no login go to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: signin.php?action=nologin'); 
}
if(isset($account)) {
     require_once("{$account}.php");
} else {
?>
```

And here's the bottom of the dashboard

```
<?php require_once('inc/footer.php'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I have also included my PHP code of the withdraw page.

Here's the top of the withdraw page

```
<?php
// Seddeo Page System - Customer Dashboard
DEFINE("IN_SEDDEO", 1);

$pageName = "Account Settings";
$body = "dashboard-settings";

require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once('inc/header.php');

$account = $_GET['account'];
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

// If no login go to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: signin.php?action=nologin'); 
}
?>
```

Very bottom of the page

```
<?php require_once('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

So I hope somebody can help me resolve this issue, thank you.

Ok so here's my header file

```
<?php
// Create a session only if we don't have one 
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) 
{ session_start(); 
}

// User data
$myID      = ($_SESSION["userID"])      ?: null; 
$ownerIP      = ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])      ?: null; 
$myUser      = ($_SESSION["username"])      ?: null; 

if(!empty($myUser)) {
    $db->update('UPDATE members SET lastActive = NOW() WHERE username = ?', array($myUser)); 
    $info = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ?", array($myUser));
    $rank = $info['rank'];
    $regIP = $info['ownerIP'];
    $lastLoginIP = $info['lastLoginIP'];
    $id = $info['memberID'];
    $my_Avatar = $info['my_Avatar'];
    $myMembership = $info['myMembership'];
    $account_type = $info['account_type'];
}

// Verified Page 
if(!DEFINED("IN_SEDDEO")) 
{ 
die("You cannot access this file directly."); 
}

if($account_type == 1) {
$isAccount = true;
} else {
$isAccount = false;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- viewport meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="MartPlace - Complete Online Multipurpose Marketplace HTML Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="app, app landing, product landing, digital, material, html5">


    <title>Seddeo - <?php echo $pageName; ?></title>

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lnr-icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trumbowyg.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>
```

Comment: does your page redirect?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe more.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi , Yes the page redirect's to the new page in loads it perfect. The page Name just doesn't update.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi Ok so what i mean is when a customer goes to their dashboard it show's at the top of the title MarketPlace - Dashboard and when a user click on the link the redirects them to dashboard.php?account=update-account. It suppose to switch to MarketPlace - Account Settings. It doesn't change when a user clicks the link it stays at MarketPlace - Dashboard

Comment: please show your header.php file

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I have included my header file

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i can see, the `inc/header.php` file is included **BEFORE** the `account.php` file.

You will see that the `$pageName` variable is used in `inc/header.php` file.

but the value of `$pageName` is only changed **AFTER** the the `inc/header.php` file is included... meaning that the value will **ALWAYS** be it's initial value, i.e: `Dashboard`

In summary:

```
dashboard.php
  \-> $pageName = 'Dashboard'
  \-> loads header.php
  \-> $pageName is still 'Dashboard'
  \-> <title> tag uses $pageName
  \-> load account.php
  \-> $pageName = "Account Settings" (which doesn't matter since it has already been used in header.php
```

---

To solve your problem i would suggest add the following to `dashboard.php`

**BEFORE** this line:

```
require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once('inc/header.php');
```

```
$titles = [
 'dashboard.php' => 'Dashboard',
 'dashboard.php?account=update-account' => 'Account Settings'
];
$pageName = isset( $titles[ $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ] ) ? $titles[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ] : 'Dashboard'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have tried your code in it still showing data from the dashboard page, Its like the page is not changing name.